# Transform one XML format to another XML format using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, spring-mvc

I have a code with XML output as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>abc</name>
        <id>1</id>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>klm</name>
        <id>2</id>
    </product>
</products>
```

I want the same XML to be displayed in following format as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>
            <value>abc</value>
            <unit></unit>
        </name>
        <id>
            <value>1</value>
            <unit></unit>
        </id>
        <product>
        <name>
            <value>klm</value>
            <unit></unit>
        </name>
        <id>
            <value>2</value>
            <unit></unit>
        </id>
</product>
```

How can i do it using XSLT?

I am using Spring environment. XML tags for product are variable. These vary by kind of products. The code to generate XML is

```
JAXBContext jc;
try {
   jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(cla);
   Marshaller m;
   m = jc.createMarshaller();
   m.marshal(obj, out); 
} catch (JAXBException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit:
product may have weight attribue, so there will also be a tag of

```
<weight>10lbs<weight>
```

This tage will break into

```
<weight>
    <value>10</value>
    <unit>lbs</unit>
</weight>
```

Comment: What data goes into the `<unit />` tag?

Comment: Its null for name but has value if the tag is weight or speed, etc.

Comment: Can you provide that case in your example code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample stylesheet [edited to reflect the new requirement with the weight element]:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="products">
   <xsl:copy>
     <product>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="product/*"/>
     </product>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product/*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <value>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </value>
     <unit></unit>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product/weight" priority="3">
   <xsl:copy>
     <value>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '')"/>
     </value>
     <unit>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '0123456789', '')"/>
     </unit>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply that to the sample input

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>abc</name>
        <id>1</id>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>klm</name>
        <id>2</id>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>foo</name>
        <id>3</id>
        <weight>10lbs</weight>
     </product>
</products>
```

I get

```
<products>
   <product>
      <name>
         <value>abc</value>
         <unit/>
      </name>
      <id>
         <value>1</value>
         <unit/>
      </id>
      <name>
         <value>klm</value>
         <unit/>
      </name>
      <id>
         <value>2</value>
         <unit/>
      </id>
      <name>
         <value>foo</value>
         <unit/>
      </name>
      <id>
         <value>3</value>
         <unit/>
      </id>
      <weight>
         <value>10</value>
         <unit>lbs</unit>
      </weight>
   </product>
</products>
```

Based on Alejandro's comment I might have misread the wanted output and you don't want to merge products, in that case use

```
<xsl:stylesheet
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product/*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <value>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </value>
     <unit></unit>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product/weight" priority="3">
   <xsl:copy>
     <value>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '')"/>
     </value>
     <unit>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '0123456789', '')"/>
     </unit>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then you get

```
<products>
   <product>
      <name>
         <value>abc</value>
         <unit/>
      </name>
      <id>
         <value>1</value>
         <unit/>
      </id>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>
         <value>klm</value>
         <unit/>
      </name>
      <id>
         <value>2</value>
         <unit/>
      </id>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>
         <value>foo</value>
         <unit/>
      </name>
      <id>
         <value>3</value>
         <unit/>
      </id>
      <weight>
         <value>10</value>
         <unit>lbs</unit>
      </weight>
   </product>
</products>
```

Comment: @Martin Honnen When I apply this stylesheet all XML tages are lost and xbc 1 klm 2 is the output.

Comment: Faryal, are you sure the input is exactly as you posted? It sounds as if you are using a vastly different input document with the posted stylesheets, probably with elements in some namespace you haven't shown to us.

Comment: This is exactly the output generated by code:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<product>
  <category>Laptop</category> 
  <description>Lenovo ThinkPad X100e 2876 - Athlon Neo MV-40 / 1.6 GHz - RAM 3 GB - HDD 250 GB - Mobility Radeon HD 3200 - 3G Mobile Broadband - Gigabit Ethernet - WLAN : 802.11b/g/n Bluetooth 2.1 - TPM - Windows 7 Pro - 11.6" Widescreen TFT 1366 x 768 ( WXGA ) - camer</description> 
  <id>1</id> 
  <language>English</language> 
  <weight>0lbs</weight>
  <wireless>WLAN : 802.11b/g/n Bluetooth 2.1</wireless> 
</product>

Comment: Well in your original post you have a root element named `products`, I don't see that in the code in your latest comment. Please clarify and edit your question to show the input you have and the output you want.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: I think there is no need for merging `product`s, it's just an error of desired output indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/products">
  <xsl:for-each select="product">
   <xsl:element name="product">
     <xsl:element name="name">
       <xsl:element name="value"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:element>
       <xsl:element name="unit"/>
     </xsl:element>
     <xsl:element name="id">
       <xsl:element name="value"><xsl:value-of select="id"/></xsl:element>
       <xsl:element name="unit"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use <xsl:for-each>

Comment: @conqenator When I apply this stylesheet all XML tages are lost and xbc 1 klm 2 is the output

Comment: @Faryal: Sorry, I cannot test the code right now. I have fixed it now. See me Edit.

Comment: @Faryal: you are either running the stylesheet incorrectly, or you are viewing the output incorrectly.

Comment: @TOUDIdel "You shouldn't use `<xsl:for-each>`". That's a comment from someone with a little knowledge. A little knowledge is a dangerous thing. The xsl:for-each instruction is there for a purpose. Its use here is quite defensible. If I were to criticize this code, my first comment would be on the use of xsl:element instead of literal result elements, which is quite unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: @Michael: In my defense.. If you see the revisions.. I did use literal xml elements first. Then edited to have xsl:element to be on the safer side since I wasn't sure what XSLT parser was being used in this case.